# JSON return null or char code

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

When i encode my array from MySQL db (latin1_general_ci) they turn into null

my php:

```
    $con=mysql_connect("mysql6.000webhost.com", $dbuser , $dbpass)or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("host")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql = "select codcli , razao from cliente";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $json = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $json[]=$row;
        }
    }
    mysql_close($con); 
    echo json_encode($json); 
}else{
    die("Error");
}
```

now if I change to

```
$json[]=array_map('utf8_encode', $row)
```

it will return the char code like

```
COM\u00c9RCIO
```

and I'd like to show

```
COMÉRCIO
```

is that possible? or I should work with that inside my android app?

Comment: Text in JSON is encoded. In other words, `COM\u00c9RCIO` is the correct JSON representation of `COMÉRCIO`.

Comment: Try to json_decode()

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen ok but when this data is parsed inside my android app the string will appear COM\u00c9RCIO or COMÉRCIO?

Comment: @LucasBertollo If you are doing it right then it should be displayed as `COMÉRCIO`.